# Vector labels seem to be covered by colored features/polygons in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm having trouble displaying the feature's label. From my code I can color each polygon and I want it to display the label name of each polygon as well. It only shows the coloring of the image functions below in the setStyle section, but in the lebels defined in

```
var layer_tambon = new ol.layer.Vector ({
    source: layer_source,
    style: function (features) {
       labelStyle.getText (). setText (features.get ('TAM_NAM_T'));
       return style;
    },
    declutter: true
});
```

It doesn't show results. I find that it is overlapped. If the operation is disabled `features [i] .setStyle (style_mid_risk_area);` It will display the label name How do I fix it so it shows

This is my code.

```
var style_low_risk_area = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [0, 250, 0, 1]
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: [100, 100, 100, 1],
        width: 1
    })
});

var style_mid_risk_area = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [250, 250, 0, 1]
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: [100, 100, 100, 1],
        width: 1
    })

});

var style_hight_risk_area = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [250, 0, 0, 1]
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: [100, 100, 100, 1],
        width: 1
    })
});

var labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
        overflow: true,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#fff',
        width: 3
        })
    })
});

var tambonStyle_default = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [150, 150, 150, 1]
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: [100, 100, 100, 1],
        width: 1
    })
});

var style = [ tambonStyle_default , labelStyle ];

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([102.291163, 12.809588]),
        zoom: 9
    })
});

var layer_source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'geojson/tambon_wgs84.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

var layer_tambon = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: layer_source,
    style: function(features) {
        labelStyle.getText().setText(features.get('TAM_NAM_T'));
        return style;
    },
    declutter: true
});

myFuntion();
map.addLayer(layer_tambon);

function myFuntion(){
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost/Prediction_DHF2/quryDataJson.php',true);
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
        var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        var data_tambon_code;
        var data_risk;
            var key = layer_source.on ('change', function(evt) {
                if (evt.target.getState() === 'ready') {
                    ol.Observable.unByKey(key);
                    var features = layer_source.getFeatures();
                    var tambon_code_i;
                    var tambon_code_j;
                    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                        tambon_code_i = features[i].get('TAMBON_COD');
                        for (var j = 0; j < ourData.length; j++) {
                            tambon_code_j = ourData[j].TAMBON_COD;
                            data_risk_j = ourData[j].L_RISK;
                            if (tambon_code_i == tambon_code_j ){
                                if (data_risk_j<8.00){
                                    //console.log('low',tambon_code_i);
                                    features[i].setStyle(style_low_risk_area);
                                }else if (data_risk_j<=16.00){
                                    //console.log('mid',tambon_code_i);
                                    features[i].setStyle(style_mid_risk_area);
                                }else if (data_risk_j>16.01){
                                    //console.log('hight',tambon_code_i);
                                    features[i].setStyle(style_hight_risk_area);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }   
    ourRequest.send();
}
```

This is the end result.

[image]

If I turn off the `features [i] .setStyle (style_mid_risk_area);` Found that the label name is up But on other lines that are not closed Up but only color

[image]

Comment: My answer was completely wrong, I mixed up a few things, so I deleted it.

Comment: Never mind, thank you for the answer just a moment ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a style on your features which overrides the layer style

Instead of using `setStyle` on the features you could `set` a property called `'risk_style'`

```
                        if (tambon_code_i == tambon_code_j ){
                            if (data_risk_j<8.00){
                                //console.log('low',tambon_code_i);
                                features[i].set('risk_style', style_low_risk_area);
                            }else if (data_risk_j<=16.00){
                                //console.log('mid',tambon_code_i);
                                features[i].set('risk_style', style_mid_risk_area);
                            }else if (data_risk_j>16.01){
                                //console.log('hight',tambon_code_i);
                                features[i].set('risk_style', style_hight_risk_area);
                            }
                        }
```

Then in your layer style function you can set the text for the layer style and return an array containing that and the `risk_style` for the feature (or default if there is no `risk_style` set)

```
var layer_tambon = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: layer_source,
    style: function(features) {
        labelStyle.getText().setText(features.get('TAM_NAM_T'));
        return [features.get('risk_style') || tambonStyle_default, labelStyle];
    },
    declutter: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. It's already showing Labels from your suggestions. Thanks again for the help.